# Oracle - append hint and no constraints are checked

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've reading about insert with `Direct-path` (hint append) in Oracle and some explanations says that no constraints are checked.

What exactly are ignored in this checks? Isn't clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is the FKs that are not checked. Primary keys, and unique keys are checked (if unique indexes are there, as they should). There are also some differences in how NOT NULL is handled. Also, triggers are not fired. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-8D6EF7DE-A433-4198-BE57-D2826C4F36D9)